# ListView does not update at run-time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

I have been trying this all day, but without any luck. I am able to display the UserControl, but I am not able to figure out why the Columns won't show even though I have set them in the XAML. Also, I am not sure if the data is showing either because the form opens up blank.

This is part of my class library that I am calling from another program. However, it always shows a blank form and nothing is being updated.

Below is my UserControl code.

```
public partial class DisplayData : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> _DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

    public DisplayData()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Window window = new Window();
        window.Content = new UserControl();
        window.Show();
    }

    public void AddDataToList(int ID, string Name)
    {
        _DataCollection.Add(new Data
        {
            StudentID = ID,
            StudentName = Name
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataCollection { get { return _DataCollection; } }
}

public struct Data
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

Below is how I am calling it:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DisplayData displayData = new DisplayData();
        displayData.AddDataToList(2, "John");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

And the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConsoleApplication1.DisplayData"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="210">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataCollection}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="ID" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StudentID}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding StudentName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

EDIT
I would also like to add that:

1. It will not show me the correct size
2. I can't even see the column headings on the form
3. No data updates either.

Also, not sure if this helps, but I have added this as a WPF UserControl to my existing project.

Comment: Maybe you should try creating a new project (WPF one) instead of console application. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all of your code, I can't tell if this is the problem (or only problem) or not, but you need to bind the `DataContext` property. Your listview knows the columns are bound to some properties, but they don't know where those properties come from (the class).

You will also want to look into INotifyPropertyChanged (maybe not for this project, but in general) as well. It's a bit to explain, so you can just look up what it does, but it's a huge part of WPF bindings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx

Your best move would to be to find a good tutorial on bindings and how to set up your listview. It's hard to really just figure out without some background know-how. It was for me, anyway. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If you run your program under the debugger, it should print out any data binding errors in the Output window. That can be helpful to figure out what is going wrong with bindings.

Comment: thanks for your comments Yatrix & Andy. I did try putting it through the debugger but I do not see any warings or errors. I am also not able to figure out why window.Content = new UserControl() will not display the Headers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no XAML pro, but in the documenation they have a different binding text: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750972.aspx

Try

```
DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=StudentID}"
```

Comment: thanks for response. i just tried adding the path as well but the form displays with no data. Also, the form is MUCH larger than the dimensions i have set (200x100). Not sure why this happens.. Also, I do not want to take full-credit of the code above. I was learning it from here today: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1 but badly stuck.

Comment: I would also like to add that i was trying the same with the Windows ListView and i am able to update data to it (using .Update()) and also display it properly. I am not sure why it doesn't work for WPF.

Comment: @Vicky Don't expect similarities between a winform control and a wpf control and you won't be disappointed.

Comment: @Yatrix: I started my WPF self-training yesterday and thought why not use ListView as the first lesson. I've been struggling for more than 10 hours on this without luck :(

Comment: @Vicky WPF is awesome, flexible and powerful. Just take your WinForm knowledge and throw it out with WPF. You'll love it when you get used to it, but it's very, very different.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
public struct Data
```

into

```
public class Data
```

I have also been working on ListView all day today and if there is one thing I can say about it is that it is finicky. It may just not want to take in a struct.

Edit: Here is my working ListView

```
<ListView Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Name="listTableItem" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"
                Width="75"
            />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value"
                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Value}"
                Width="500"
            />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: David: yes, I read your answer and changed it to class. However, it still will not work. 1. It will not show me the correct size. 2. I can't even see the column headings on the form. 3. No data updates either. :(

Comment: After looking at your code more closely, I think my examples may not work since I am manually adding items to TreeView.Items whereas you are using a data source. I included my working ListView code so you can compare. Hopefully it can at least help you rule out some things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind your DataContext to the codebehind.  See below.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConsoleApplication1.DisplayData"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="210">
```

Comment: figabytes: i have incorporated your suggestion to my XAML but still no luck. :(

Answer (score 0):

As couple other posters noted you need to set the DataContext (as in figabytes answer):

```
<UserControl x:Class="ConsoleApplication1.DisplayData"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="210">
```

The other problem is that you're not making any attempt to show the control. The bellow code creates a window object and places the control you created as content. After that you just call Show() or ShowDialog() and you should the result of your work.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        DisplayData displayData = new DisplayData();
        displayData.AddDataToList(2, "John");

        Window window = new Window();
        window.Content = displayData;

        window.ShowDialog();
}
```